# make a servlet that intercept svn requests

Tags: java, svn

I wanna create a servlet that intercepts svn requests and redirects them to the real svn server, so that the svn client will not know about the real server.

Could you give some hints please ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can choose a simplier path, such as using a webdav / http protocol for SVN, and configuring an Apache virtual host which will do the redirection (like a standard reverse proxy) ?